# Is there a better way to switch between multiple windows in emacs gdb besides C-x-o?

Tags: emacs, gdb

I'm using gdb-many-windows, which contains five windows to switch between. Is there a shortcut I can use to get to a specific window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some people find [WindMove](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove) more convenient than <kbd>C-x o</kbd>. It allows you to navigate between windows using Shift + arrow keys.

Comment: Does Terminal 2.2.1 not support modified arrow keys?

Comment: I don't use Macs, but you could try to type "CTRL-v right-arrow" and "CTRL-v Shift-right-arrow" in bash and see if it produces different escape sequences. If not, you could still use WindMove by binding the respective functions to different keyboard shortcuts, of course.

Answer (score 8):

You probably already know that `C-x o` gets you to the next window.  You can extend this to go to any arbitrary window with `C-u <windowoffset> C-x o`.

So, you can use `C-u 2 C-x o` to switch to the second window ahead of your current one.

This wraps around the window list (so in your case of 5 windows you could do `C-u 4 c-x o` to go back one.

You can also use negative numbers as well to go backwards.

Lastly, it takes a bit more setup, but Thomas's suggestion to use WindMove is very useful.  It wasn't configured by default for me to any useful key binding.  I add the following snippet to my (mac) .emacs file, whch lets me switch windows via control-arrow (you will need to reload .emacs by starting up or via 'M-x load-file')

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[ 5 d") 'windmove-left)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[ 5 c") 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[ 5 a") 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[ 5 b") 'windmove-down)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly useful links:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindowNumberingMode

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NumberedWindows

Edit: If you decide to use WindowNumberingMode (that's what I use) you might find it useful to pin buffers to windows (so, for instance, Meta-1 switches to the buffer you expect it to switch to, not just the first window). One way of pinning is described in [Pin Emacs buffers to windows (for cscope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765/pin-emacs-buffers-to-windows-for-cscope).

Answer (score 1):

Window switching is so important in emacs, I have these settings.(Still feel these are not good enough).. 
may help someone else..

```
(global-set-key "\M-t" 'other-window)   ;; was transpose words
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x O") (lambda () (interactive) (other-window -1))) ;; back one
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-o") (lambda () (interactive) (other-window 2))) ;; forward t
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [switch-window.el](https://github.com/dimitri/switch-window).
You can choose a window by visual way with 'switch-window'.

[Image of using switch-window](http://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/t/tomoya/20100807/20100807121627.jpg)